# Is there any way to use @after and @before in Karate?

Tags: karate, automation-testing

Analyzing if I can customize a Karate html Report can anyone help me in using @after and @before in Karate?

Comment: assume that this is not supported by karate. also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72345404/143475